# Firebase not updated with new data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

so in the below code, user is prompted to input text into the 2 TextInputs and which will update the data in the state and when the user hits "Save profile changes" button or TouchableOpacity, that sends the data in the state to the Firebase database.

This doesn't seem to update the database though. Can anyone shed some light on what the issue here might be?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import Fire from '../Fire';
import * as Analytics from 'expo-firebase-analytics';

export default class UpdateProfileScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            name: 'no name',
          about: '',
        zoom: '',
        net: '',
        profile: ''
    };
  }

  onPressUpdate = async () => {
      const user = {
        name: this.state.name,
        profile: this.state.about,
        zoom: this.state.zoom
      };
      await Fire.shared.updateProfile(user);
    };

  onChangeTextName = name => this.setState({ name });
  onChangeProfile = profile => this.setState({ profile });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}></View>

          <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri: 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png'}}/>
          <View style={styles.body}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.nameInput}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeTextName}
            value={this.state.name}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.description}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeProfile}
            value={this.state.profile}
          />
            <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => {
                Analytics.logEvent('UserZoomButton', {
                  screen: 'UpdateProfile',
                  purpose: 'User clicks on "Zoom" button',
                });
              }}>
                <Text>Zoom</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => {
                Analytics.logEvent('SaveProfileChangesButton', {
                  screen: 'UpdateProfile',
                  purpose: 'User clicks on "Save Profile Changes" button',
                });
                this.onPressUpdate;
              }}>
              <Text>Save Profile Changes</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Fire.shared.getname(net_result =>
      Fire.shared.getname(name_result =>
        Fire.shared.getprofile(profile_result => {
          this.setState({net:net_result, name:name_result, profile:profile_result})
        })));
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? What is the response from the promise? `const response = await Fire.shared.updateProfile(user);`

Comment: @NiyasNazar nothing is printed for response, so I put console.log("inside onpressupdate") in the beginning of onPressUpdate to print anything, but again, nothing was printed. It seems like the save profile change button isn't even triggering onpressupdate.... hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the paranthesis. Replace `this.onPressUpdate;` with `this.onPressUpdate();`.

Comment: response is undefined. what else should I do to track down the problem?

Comment: @sea What is `Fire`? Is that a library? I think you need to debug inside that.